# Partially flattening/Filtering cats Monads

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have been jumping through hoops trying to solve a problem with cats Monad.

Given the type constructor `F[_]` for which we have the implict `F: Monad[F]`

If we have the type `List[F[Option[T]]]` is it possible to flatten this type such that we end up with `List[F[T]]`

In effect I would like to filter any instances in the list where the inner Option is None.

Ultimately I want to end up with `F[List[T]]` which I can achieve using sequence on the partially flattened `List[F[T]]` but would be very interested in any way of achieving this in a single operation.

Cheers

Terry

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [cats.FunctorFilter](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/FunctorFilter.html) which provides a method `mapFilter(F[A])(A => Option[B]): F[B]`

```
val lfos: List[F[Option[String]]] = List(F.pure(Some("a")))

val lfs: List[F[String]] = lfos.map(_.mapFilter(identity))

val fls1: F[List[String]] = lfs.sequence

val fls2: F[List[String]] = lfos.traverse(_.mapFilter(identity))

val fls3: F[List[String]] = lfos.traverseFilter(identity)
```